# How to using command sql get random 10 rows in php

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I using sql in php, but, result not show:

```
test(id, name, type, category_id);
```

and my sql is:

```
select top 10( id, name) from test order by NewId()
```

How tio fix it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Example from this [post](http://plutov.by/post/mysql_useful_queries):

```
SELECT * FROM `table_name` ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT * from test ORDER BY RAND() LIMIT 10
```

Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

```
select top 10( id, name) from test
ORDER BY RAND()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
     id, 
     name 
FROM test 
ORDER BY RAND() 
LIMIT 0,10
```